# Why does the motor "flinches" when its motor starts spinning?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, everyday-life, torque

I'm wondering why motor "flinches" when it starts spinning.
Is there any physics law causing this?
If so, if a satellite in space has a rotating parts in it then would the satellite also moves due to the same reason?

Comment: Are you referring to the tendency of a motor to rotate opposite the direction of its rotor?

Comment: Yes, I had no idea how to interpret this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every action has an equal and opposite reaction. The torque that accelerates the rotor is associated with an opposite torque on the motor body. If the motor is on flexible mounts, that torque will rotate the body until the mounts can provide enough torque to balance it. Of course, the mounts then torque whatever they're connected to, but it may have sufficient inertia that you don't notice its response.

If the motor is delivering torque to something else, the effect is stronger: the mounts have to balance both the acceleration torque and the output torque.

Without the mounts, the body of the motor would continue to spin. That's the working principle of a [reaction wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel), commonly used to orient spacecraft in space.

Comment: I'm wondering how the action reaction pair would be in this setting. If the giant wheel rotates, then would the rest of the structure rotates in different direction? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qed6i.jpg

Comment: You also need some other device, not a reaction wheel. Without that, external toques will make the overall angular momentum uncontrollable. In low Earth orbit, magnetic torquers work for small to medium sized spacecraft; otherwise, we use rockets. I presume the thing in your picture would be operated at the right total angular momentum, controlled by rockets, for the wheel  to spin at the desired rate while the stem doesn't spin.